# Read in Certain Sheets From Excel Workbook

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

I have a work book that has 10 sheets: Half has the word "Survey" in its sheet name and the other half has the word "Census" in its sheet name.

I want to read in all the sheets that has the word "Survey" in its sheet name and append them into a separate workbook.

Sheet names are: WA Survey, Survey MD, DC Survey, VA Survey, Survey GA.

What I have:

```
 library(XLConnect)
 wb <- loadWorkbook("Data.xls")
 dataMD <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet = "Survey MD", startCol = 1, endCol = 10)
 dataWA <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet = "Survey WA", startCol = 1, endCol = 10)
 dataDC <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet = "Survey DC", startCol = 1, endCol = 10)
 dataVA <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet = "Survey VA", startCol = 1, endCol = 10)
 dataGA <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet = "Survey GA", startCol = 1, endCol = 10)
 total <- merge(dataMD,dataWA,dataDC,dataVA,dataGA,by="ID")
```

How can I make this simpler? I was hoping I can complete this task in 3-4 lines?

Comment: Is this a school assignment?  Why does it matter specifically 4 lines instead of 8 lines?  Why does it matter so much?  Regardless, if the code's working and you just want to reduce the number of lines then th question belongs on [Stack Exchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the readxl package like this and filter the Survey data sheets before reading everything in one go.

```
library(readxl)

# file including path if needed
file <- "Data.xls" 
# read the sheets and only keep the Survey sheets
sheets <- excel_sheets(file)
sheets <- sheets[grep("Survey", sheets)]

# read the data, only first 10 columns (A:J)
excel_data <- lapply(sheets, read_excel, path = file, range = cell_cols("A:J") )
```

You end up with a list of data. If all columns are identical you can use `do.call("rbind", excel_data)` or `dplyr::bind_rows`

Answer (score 1):

You can define an object with sheet names and then use `lapply` to get a list of imported Excel files.

```
sheets <- paste("Survey", c("MD", "WA", "DC", "VA", "GA"))
excel.list <- lapply(sheets, function(x) 
  readWorksheetFromFile("Data.xls", sheet=x, startCol=1, endCol=10))
```

Now you can work over this list to get the final data.frame you want.

Consider using `do.call(rbind, Excel.list))` if and only if all your Excel sheets contains same variables in same order.

Comment: Or, `sheets <- grep("Survey", getSheets("Data.xls"), value = TRUE)` to make it a bit more general